# Detecting HTTP Request fail on server

Tags: http, jakarta-ee, transactions, client-server, distributed-system

I'm developing an HTTP server, which handles transactional requests from clients. They'll communicate through a highly unreliable wireless network, so I'm worried about consistency of data on server DB. Here's how I handle `POST` requests:

```
void doPost(request, response)
{
    transaction = newTransaction();
    processBody(request);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

When I never receive a request, there is no problem. Client just gets `timeout error` and no transaction is performed. However, what will happen if the **response** gets lost on the network? Surely, a client will still receive `timeout error`, but this time transaction will be completed on the server without client knowing that! This is unfortunate case I need to deal with.

So, my question is: how do I detect whether a response has been delivered and rollback the transaction otherwise?

I code my server app using JavaEE and host it on Glassfish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured this one out. HTTP/TCP protocol stack doesn't have facilities to detect a **response drop**. However, it handles **request drop** perfectly well, so that I only need to send POST request from server to client, like that:

```
void doPost(request, response)
{
    transaction = newTransaction();
    try {
        var result = processBody(request);
        sendPOSTToClient(result);
        transaction.commit();
    catch (IOException e) {
        transaction.rollback(); // network partition occured
    }
}
```